# Strip all tags from an XML file

Tags: php, asp.net, xml, xslt

I have a large XML file I would like to strip all the tags and leave node values only. I want each node value in a separate line. How can I do that?

Can I use a free software to do it or use a PHP or ASP.NET Code. I looked at XSLT option also. It is probably too much for RegEX. I explored PHP options looked at `simplexml_load_file()`, `strip_tags()`, `get_file_contents()` but failed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- a comment -->
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
                <address>
                         <city>Melbourne </city>
                         <zip>01803 </zip>
                </address>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>

</catalog>
```

**Edit:** This is what I tried, among other things.

```
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_file('myxml.xml');
echo strip_tags($xml);

?>
```

Comment: `strip_tags()` should work. Could you post how you tried to use it?

Comment: I feel like this question sortof leads to the other question of how to parse tags http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags -- All I'll say is be careful.

Comment: @ConnorPeet added code snippet for `strip_tags`. I dont get any output from this because $xml is basically an array

Comment: Swap `simplexml_load_file()` for `file_get_contents()` in your last snippet and it will work.

Comment: @DaveRandom tried that. It then shows everything without line break which is kind of weird.

Comment: That's because you're looking at it in a browser. Passing through `nl2br()` and you'll see it all on seperate lines

Comment: Look into using an XSL transform.  You should be able to format the XML data easily with that.  http://php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php

Comment: @DaveRandom  little code will be helpful. I have already tried quite a bit.

Comment: See if `echo implode("<br>\n", preg_split('/\s\s+/', trim(strip_tags(file_get_contents('myxml.xml')))));` gives you what you want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do ya:

```
<?php
$xml = file_get_contents('myxml.xml');
$xml = nl2br($xml);
echo strip_tags($xml,"<br>");
?>
```

The reason you were missing line breaks was because in XML, it is stored as plaintext linebreaks `\n` whereas when displaying as HTML you must have explicit `<br>` linebreaks. Because of this the good PHP folks made a handy function called `nl2br()` to do this for you.

Comment: BTW I would like to have a code where I can manipulate each line. I need to add somethin before the node and add something after.

Answer (score 5):

**Here is a short and simple XSLT solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="text()">
  <br /><xsl:value-of select="concat(.,'&#xA;')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document** (would work on *any* XML document):

```
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <address>
            <city>Melbourne </city>
            <zip>01803 </zip>
        </address>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

**the wanted result is produced:**

```
<br/>Empire Burlesque
<br/>Bob Dylan
<br/>USA
<br/>Columbia
<br/>10.90
<br/>Melbourne 
<br/>01803 
<br/>1985
<br/>Hide your heart
<br/>Bonnie Tyler
<br/>UK
<br/>CBS Records
<br/>9.90
<br/>1988
```

**and it is displayed by the browser as:**

Empire Burlesque

Bob Dylan

USA

Columbia

10.90

Melbourne 

01803 

1985

Hide your heart

Bonnie Tyler

UK

CBS Records

9.90

1988

Comment: Thanks! this will help me too. I was looking for anything by the way, just wanted to strip the tags.